# Powershell: All new-objects are not created equal?

Tags: powershell

I'm working on some short demo scripts for a presentation on powershell and of course one of my own simple demos has me perplexed. The purpose of this demo is to show different ways to create objects in powershell. Here's my code:

```
$file = ls 'C:\temp' | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.txt'}
$file.FullName
$path = 'C:\temp\jdh.txt'
$newfile = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -ArgumentList $path
$newfile.FullName

$file.GetType()
$newfile.GetType()
$file
$newfile

$file | Get-Content | out-null
$newfile | Get-Content | out-null
```

Simple right? Create two FileInfo objects via different methods and read them. The output shows the files are identical:

```
C:\temp\jdh.txt
C:\temp\jdh.txt

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                               
True     True     FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo                                                               
True     True     FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo                                                               

LastWriteTime : 4/10/2013 3:38:29 PM
Length        : 46046
Name          : jdh.txt


LastWriteTime : 4/10/2013 3:38:29 PM
Length        : 46046
Name          : jdh.txt
```

However, when Get-Content tries to read the $newfile object, I get the following error:

```
Get-Content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the 
input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:16 char:12
+ $newfile | Get-Content | out-null
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\temp\jdh.txt:PSObject) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

So I noticed in the error it says PSObject which confuses me because in my ouput it seems $newfile is a FileInfo object. So the next logical thing I figured to do would be to typecast $newfile into type [System.IO.FileInfo]. That yielded the same error, except now instead of PSObject it shows FileInfo as the type. So how is it that I'm getting that error if $file and $newfile appear to be identical and get-content worked on $file? Is there some subtle difference when you use the new-object command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I traced the binding with the object created using `New-Object` and the problem is that `Get-Content` couldn't bind to any properties on the `FileInfo` info object.

You can check this out with this command:

```
Trace-Command -psHost -Name ParameterBinding {$newFile | gc}
Trace-Command -psHost -Name ParameterBinding {$file | gc}
```

So when you look at the trace of the one that binds successfully you'll see that Literal path is bound to the property starting with `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::` which is PsPath. So on closer inspection comparing the object properties when piping to `Get-Member` you'll see the one that works has these note properties where as the one created with `New-Object` does not -

- PSChildName
- PSDrive
- PSIsContainer
- PSParentPath
- PSPath
- PSProvider

Taking a look at the `Get-Content` cmdlet parameters we can see that `LiteralPath` has an alias of `PsPath`:

```
(Get-Command -Name Get-Content).ParameterSets

  Parameter Name: LiteralPath
    ParameterType = System.String[]
    Position = 0
    IsMandatory = True
    IsDynamic = False
    HelpMessage =
    ValueFromPipeline = False
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = True
    ValueFromRemainingArguments = False
    Aliases = {PSPath}
    Attributes =
      System.Management.Automation.AliasAttribute
      System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
```

If you add a property to the `New-Object` created `FileInfo` it will work:

```
$newFile | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PsPath -Value 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\jdh.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, particularly the Trace-Command information.

Answer (score -1):

Remember, New-Object just creates an instance of a PowerShell object...it has not written anything to file.  using

```
Test-Path $path
```

shows that the file does not exist yet.  So, adding some code to actually create the file and then assign back to it, will yield you not errors.

```
Test-Path $path

$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $path
1..10 | % {
      $stream.WriteLine($s)
}
$stream.close()

$newfile = Get-Content $path

$file | Get-Content | out-null
$newfile | Get-Content | out-null
```

We assign back to $newfile because it is a reference.  It doesn't get updated automatically if we create the file after the fact.

Comment: I should have mentioned for my example the file was pre-existing. The output indicates both $file and $newfile point to the same path and that file contains data.

Comment: It's not that file doesn't exist. Even if the FileInfo is created with New-Object using the full path, the pipe still fails because it's missing the PsPath property.